# Need help with this kind of animation

Tags: animation, modifiers, camera

I am quite new to animation & blender. I need help of Masters on how to create this kind of animation in Blender?  I have tried follow path animation but it doesn't work as there is a pinching of bottles in the beginning. So I was thinking maybe they have used some kind of particle system? much appreciated.

[image: Animation camera setup/modifiers]

Comment: Hi, what have you tried? You should try to create the animation, and then ask for help when you are stuck with a specific problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, i have tried follow path but it doesn't work as there is a pinching of bottles in the beginning. So I was thinking maybe they have used some kind of particle system?

Comment: Please add that new info as an [edit] to you question so other users will see it without needing to read comments. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can get something similar this way:

- Create your object, keyframe it at frame 0 and frame 30, parent it to an empty (1), parent this empty to a second empty (2):

[image]

- Create a first keyframe for empty 2, keyframe it at frame 0, move to frame 30, rotate it 90° on the X axis, keyframe again:

[image]

- Put your cursor at the center (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>), choose *Transform Orientation > 3D Cursor*, select your object and empty 1, link-duplicate with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, rotate 45° on the Z axis:

[image]

- Repeat the operation until you have your 8 objects:

[image]

- At frame 30 select one of your object, move it, rotate it the way you want, and keyframe. As they are all linked, they will all inherit the same action, it can give something like that (of course it's not exactly your animation, make something more sophisticated with both empty 2 and object animations). Invert the keyframes in order to have your animation go the other way (select keyframes and <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>-1</kbd>):

[image]

- As all your objects are different, in the *Properties panel > Object Data*, replace each object by its correct mesh:

[image]

Comment: Excellent, thanks @moonboots, exactly what i was looking for, many thanks

Comment: If that solved your issue, please consider accepting the answer @ra95 How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @moonboots, could you please explain a bit more about the last step 'Properties panel > Object Data', i didn't quite understand this one, many thanks

Comment: For the moment, in my demonstration, all the objects are the same. If some of your objects are different (like in your video, it looks like there are 2 different objects) you need to select the object, go into Properties panel > Object Data and click on the dropdown menu to select which mesh you want for this object.